# LAME executes via Terminal but not PHP. libiconv version error

Tags: php, exec, lame, libiconv

After digging for 8 hours or so and solving many other mysteries I'm ansolutely stuck now.

when I run

`lame /.../disa.mp3 /.../disa3.wav --decode -b 16 -m m`

via terminal (OSX Maverics) it works just fine, but when I try to do the same via PHP, I get an error (int(5) in result). So I added `2>&1` to my `exec`uted command. Now I get this:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/lame
Reason: Incompatible library version: lame requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0 `
```

and that would make some sense unless:

```
$ otool -L /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
/opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib:
/opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

So yeah, lame cannot load libiconv because it thinks libiconv is 7.0.0 while libiconv thinks it is 8.0.0

Any ideas?